# Divide grid in smaller cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, grids-graticules

My dataset: a **shapefile** containing squares of 1km size. It's huge, this is just a sample:
[image]

My aim: divide each cell so that the end result would be the same grid with 500m each cell. Something like this:
[image]

Since the grid is huge I would need a way to make these squares smaller automatically. Any ideas on how to do it in ArcGIS 10.3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As user30184 pointed out, there's a tool that does the trick. 
Run the tool [Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000)
Simply put your old 1km grid in the Template extent.

This will populate the coordinates of your extent.

Then fill the "Cell Size Width" and "Cell Size Height" with 500
geometry type > polygon

That's it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take a Python script approach, try out this customer grid tool, http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4e2a8fe3f297405d81747df1d1fdb45d. It should create quarters of whatever grid size you have.